# Data from Firebase did not show in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` not show any data from Firebase. I don't see any errors at logcat so I don't know why. I followed guide from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmqYd-AdmC0&t=50s) video. But still nothing. I'm using android 8.0 and API 27. Hope Somebody can help.

My Main Activity Code:

```
public class ViewProduct extends AppCompatActivity {

  DatabaseReference ref;
  ArrayList<Model> list;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private RecyclerView.Adapter viewHolder;
  private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
  SearchView searchView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_product)  ;

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("buddymealplanneruser").
                child("Products");


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.stallproductRecyclerView);
        //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //SEARCH VIEW
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchProductStall);

        //ADAPTER
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (ref!=null)
        {
             ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                     {
                         //list = new ArrayList<>();
                         list.clear();
                         for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                         {

                             list.add(ds.getValue(Model.class));

                         }
                         //ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(list);
                         //recyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder);

                         viewHolder.notifyDataSetChanged();

                     }
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                     Toast.makeText(ViewProduct.this, databaseError.getMessage(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
        }
        if (searchView !=null)
        {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    search(s);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void search(String str) {
        ArrayList<Model> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Model object : list)
        {
            if(object.getProductName().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase()))
            {
                myList.add(object);
            }
        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(myList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(viewHolder);


    }


}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder.MyViewHolder> {


    ArrayList<Model> list;
    public ViewHolder (ArrayList<Model> list)
    {
        this.list=list;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_product, viewGroup,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        myViewHolder.productName.setText(list.get(i).getProductName());
        myViewHolder.productCalorie.setText(list.get(i).getProductCalorie());
        myViewHolder.StallId.setText(list.get(i).getStallId());
        myViewHolder.productType.setText(list.get(i).getProductType());
        myViewHolder.productServing.setText(list.get(i).getProductServing());
        myViewHolder.statusProduct.setText(list.get(i).getStatusProduct());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {

        return list.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView productName, productCalorie, StallId;
        TextView productType, productServing, statusProduct;
        ImageView productImageView;

        public MyViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView){
            super((itemView));

            productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productTitle);
            productCalorie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productDescriptionCalorie);
            StallId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productDescriptionStallId);
            productType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productDescriptionType);
            productServing=itemView.findViewById(R.id.productDescriptionServing);
            statusProduct=itemView.findViewById(R.id.productDescriptionAvailibility);
            //productImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImageView);
        }


    }
}
```

My Model :

```
package com.example.buddymealplannerstall.Child;

import android.view.Display;

public class Model {

    //String  productName, productImage, productCalorie, StallId, productType, productServing, statusProduct;
    private String StallId;
    private String productCalorie;
    private String productImage;
    private String productName;
    private String productServing;
    private String productType;
    private String statusProduct;

    public Model (String StallId,
                  String productCalorie,
                  String productImage,
                  String productName,
                  String productServing,
                  String productType,
                  String statusProduct){

        this.StallId = StallId;
        this.productCalorie = productCalorie;
        this.productImage = productImage;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productServing = productServing;
        this.productType = productType;
        this.statusProduct = statusProduct;

    }

    public Model(){

    }

    public String getStallId() {
        return StallId;
    }

    public void setStallId(String stallId) {
        StallId = stallId;
    }

    public String getProductCalorie() {
        return productCalorie;
    }

    public void setProductCalorie(String productCalorie) {
        this.productCalorie = productCalorie;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductServing() {
        return productServing;
    }

    public void setProductServing(String productServing) {
        this.productServing = productServing;
    }

    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public String getStatusProduct() {
        return statusProduct;
    }

    public void setStatusProduct(String statusProduct) {
        this.statusProduct = statusProduct;
    }
}
```

Screen Shot of my firebase and my apps.

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4yeA.png)
[my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYMTn.png)

Comment: put your code in onRestart(), in onResume() instead

Comment: update: same, nothing has been displayed at my recyclerview

Comment: `buddymealplanneruser` is the name of your project? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: yes, buddymealplanner is my project's name (respond to @AlexMamo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> yes, buddymealplanner is my project's name

Please note that there is no need to add the name of your project as a child in the reference. So please change the following line of code:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("buddymealplanneruser").
            child("Products");
```

Simply to:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much, everything is fixed now. THANK YOU SO MUCH SIR. you save my day

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you are populating your list, you are sending it *empty*. From what I can see, you only add items to the list when you are restarting the activity. Try either populating it before sendinig the list, or changing the **onRestart()** for an **onStart()** or an **onResume()**.

Comment: thanks and noted I will try with onStart(), since I have tried using onResume() but still same. Update : Still same

Comment: I just checked the video you linked, the method he overrides is actually onStart().
I think the problem is that you are still sending the list empty. try to do it exactly as the video says. The adapter may not be getting the new data for some reason.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will do now. thanks for trying to help me out